# Problem with infinity?

Tags: logic, paradox, infinity, intuition

Note: See **PART 2** for a **better question**.

1 kg of matter has infinite number of parts. Infinite number of things together can make an infinite amount of matter. 1 kg is not equal to infinite amount. We face an illogical result.

Note I: The terms 'infinite divisibility' and 'infinitesimal' MAY be related.

In logical explanations, what is the mistake in this argument?

---

### PART 2

Does [1/2+1/4+1/8+1/16+...](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1/2_%2B_1/4_%2B_1/8_%2B_1/16_%2B_%E2%8B%AF) get over 1? First, we may (wrongly) think that the answer is 'Yes', but actually the answer is 'No'.

A more interesting form of this problem: **An amount starts from 0, and increase by every moment. Does it eventually get over 5?**

This is the best example of possible mistake of intuition that I faced (I have not examined all examples), and I call it a paradox:

> For a long time, the idea that such a potentially infinite summation
> could produce a finite result was considered paradoxical. - [Series
> (mathematics)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Series_(mathematics)),
> Wikipedia

Note II: '[Zeno's paradoxes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zeno%27s_paradoxes)' and '[Convergent series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_series)' may be related.

---

### A possible answer?

I think the answer to both questions may be that 'there is an infinite number of numbers or measurements between 0 and a finite number'.

Comment: There are not an infinite number of parts in 1kg of matter for one thing.

Comment: "Infinite number of things together can make an infinite amount of matter" is false: 1/2 + 1/4 + 1/8 + ... = 1, make it kilograms.

Comment: That's like saying that a pizza grows when it's cut in 10 parts instead of 8.

Comment: An infinty of finite parts makes an infinity whole while an infinity of infinitesimal parts makes a finite whole.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Isn't the series 1/2+1/4+1/8+...=1 'an infinity of finite parts'?

Comment: FWIW, I suggest reading an introductory book in Real Analysis. Stepehen Abott's "Understanding Analysis" may be a good starting point.

Answer (score 4):

The fact that "an infinite number of things together *can* make an infinite amount of matter" does not suggest that "an infinite number of things together *cannot* make a finite amount of matter. The first statement is not a logical implication, having an infinite number of things does not imply an infinite amount of matter.

If I have 10 things, they can have 10 kg of mass. If I have 10 things, they can also have a different amount of mass. If I have infinite things, they can have infinite mass. If I have infinite things, they can also have non-infinite mass. There is no contradiction here.